# Yii - CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5375' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii, frameworks

I am working with Yii 1.1.x and get the following error when performing an insert.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5375' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This happens on a table called 'competition_prizes' - there is only one primary key called 'id' (there are no other indexes or anything like that).

I can see that there is one row with the id of 5375 so that entry does already exist (as per the insert query).

The controller code is as follows has some functionality within the afterSave() functionality.

```
protected function setPrizes($prizes, $prize_type)
{
    if(!empty($prizes) && is_array($prizes))
    {
            $prize_model = CompetitionPrizes::model();
            $competition_id = $this->competition_id;
            $prize_model->deleteAll('competition_id =:competition_id AND  prize_type = :prize_type ',array(
            ':competition_id'=> $competition_id,
            ':prize_type'=> $prize_type
            ));

            foreach($prizes as $prize_position => $prize_desc) :
                $prize_model->setIsNewRecord(true);
                $prize_model->setAttributes(compact('competition_id', 'prize_position', 'prize_type','prize_desc'));
                $prize_model->save();
            endforeach;
    }   
}
```

Any ideas of how to get around the error - please note I'm new to Yii so be gentle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of the `$prize_model->setIsNewRecord(true)` (or `$prize_model->isNewRecord = true`) you also have to empty out the id attribute. As I've mentioned in my comment above, the setIsNewRecord only determines if ether the insert or update scenario is used when you call save(). If your PK is still set it will simply attempt an insert with those values set, resulting in a duplicate error.

The following should do the trick:

```
$id = NULL;
foreach($prizes as $prize_position => $prize_desc) :
   $prize_model->setIsNewRecord(true);
   $prize_model->setAttributes(compact('id', 'competition_id', 'prize_position', 'prize_type','prize_desc'));
   $prize_model->save();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting new record flag,

```
$prize_model->setIsNewRecord(true); // sometimes it may not work.
```

The issues with `setIsNewRecord` is discussed [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/566)

You can do like this also:

```
$prize_model->isNewRecord = true;
```

1. Yii forum suggest to create new object inside for loop. You can check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17027-duplicate-a-module-with-setisnewrecordtrue/)
2. You have to unset values manually like `$model->id = null;`
   You can get details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47559-insert-multiple-rows-in-database-using-loop/)

Comment: Kumar: setIsNewRecord(true) is exactly the same as isNewRecord = true; The __set magic function ends up calling the set-method. Point 2 you make is the solution to the issue, unsetting the PK attribute. setIsNewRecord just changes which scenario is used when you call save() and does not change the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach($prizes as $prize_position => $prize_desc) :     
            $prize_model->setIsNewRecord(true);
            $prize_model->id = null;
            $prize_model->setAttributes(compact('competition_id', 'prize_position', 'prize_type','prize_desc'));
            $prize_model->save();
        endforeach;
```

it should work

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer by Blizz? Is setting $prize_model->id = null significant? If so why?